# getting the last line of jenkins build

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I plugged in selenium into jenkins build. For some reason, the tests are hanging. Like it completes the full build except for one. The last test hangs. Is there a way to abort the Jenkins build, and run the last test by itself.? When you abort the jenkins build the last line of the console output is the test that failed. So I want to get the last line of the console.output and use that to run the test that hanged.

For example, when the build is aborted, the last line might be

> > tests/onboarding finished.

I want to get the last line and run the test for tests/onboarding. How do I grep for the last line when a jenkins build is aborted?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix based system, you can look for the build log like this:

```
tail -1 path/to/build/file.log
```

or

```
awk 'END{print}' path/to/build/file.log
```

or

```
sed -n '$p' path/to/build/file.log
```